# Open new tab in Unified Service Desk from Standard Web Application

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, unified-service-desk

I have a Standard Web Application hosted control in USD.  In that web app, I have javascript that is doing a window.open("http://event/?eventname=[MyEventName]").  The event has an action to navigate, but it is only navigating in the current tab; it doesn't create a new tab.  Any ideas as to what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

In response to the Event, it is necessary for your Action Call to call the Navigate Action on the desired Hosted Control, or "tab." Based on your description, it seems as though your Action Call is calling the Navigate Action on the Standard Web Application that is raising the Event. Instead, call the Navigate Action on some other Hosted Control, the one that you want to actually perform the navigation. If no Hosted Control exists for this purpose, it will be necessary to create one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I've done some more digging and wanted to clarify my situation.  

On the action of the event being called I have set the "Action:" to Popup with a url of "http://google.com".  Then I have a Windows Navigation Rule with Url of "http://google.com", Route Type of "Popup", Destination of "Tab", Action of "Route Window", Target Tab and Show Tab set to the name of the hosted control I want to show.  If I change "Action" to "Show Outside", it does popup google outside of USD.

Comment: Could you try to change your Route Type to "InPlace" and see whether this works for you?